# JavaFX open resource in sibling directory

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

I'm attempting to structure out my project so that I don't have all the sources for my application in a single folder but I'm having a problem loading an fxml file.

My project structure

```
-Project
    -MainMenu
        -MainMenu.fxml
        -MainMenuController.java
    -ChildMenu
        -ChildMenu.fxml
        -ChildMenuController.java
```

I can't seem to be able to load my *ChildMenu.fxml* file from my *MainMenuController.java* class. This is what I've tried

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ChildMenu/ChildMenu.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("./ChildMenu/ChildMenu.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ChildMenu/ChildMenu.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ChildMenu.fxml"));

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ChildMenu.fxml"));
```

I've also attempted to search both stack overflow and google but haven't found any solution to the issue.

Here is a picture of what I'm working with, I simplified my question above but it doesnt seem to help.

[image]

NetBeans builds the project into a temporary Jar so using the full path should work but its currently not, if you see the output of the build/run the full path to where the system says I am is

```
C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InventoryManagementUI
```

But if you actually look at the build logs it says that it's built/running the jar in
 `C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InventoryManagementUI\dist\run96470141\InventoryManagementUI.jar`

I must be missing something obvious.

Just for completeness here's my openWindow method

```
   public void openWindow(String window, Stage stage) {
    try {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(window));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        System.out.println("Show scene");
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open new window: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a jar resource you can us the full classpath. (e.g. `Project/childMenu/ChildMenu.fxml` would do if that is the full classpath to the file.

Comment: When using `getResource` both `.` and `..` are not supported. Either use an absolute path or call `getResource` on a `Class` within the sibling directory.

Comment: I tried that as well, however it's not currently working, I'll update the OP and show exactly whats going on.

Comment: Have you tried `inventorymanagementui/AddPartMenu/AddPartMenu.fxml`? (i.e. The actual classpath)

Comment: I attempted that and it still is throwing the same error "Failed to open new window: Location is required.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required."

Comment: On every test I've done I made sure that the spelling is all correct as well, just so that doesn't come up.

Comment: Apparently doing /inventorymanagementui/AddPartMenu/AddPartMenu.fxml worked, if someone wants to post it as an answer I will mark them correct so anyone else having a similar issue can get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to start at the beginning of the classpath with a leading forward slash like so:

```
 Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/inventorymanagementui/AddPartMenu/AddPartMenu.fxml"));
```